# How to make output filename equals to folder name

Tags: batch-file, dos, command-prompt

I have created a batch file to output a folder content into a list of names.

```
@echo off
cd /d %1
Title %~f1
dir %1 /b /l > %1\..\file_list.txt
```

How can I make the file_list.txt to be "dir name".txt?

For example I am at folder ABC and I want to output the dir list so that the final text file will be named ABC.txt instead of file_list.txt

Edit:
Thanks Alconja, it works PerfectlY. Since this is an information and learning site, would you mind expanding your answer to explain the parameters you add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=56320), I think this is what you're after:

```
@echo off&setlocal enableextensions
Title %~f1
for %%* in (%1) do set MyDir=%%~n*
dir %1 /b /l > %1\..\"%MyDir%.txt"
endlocal&goto :eof
```

Gave it a quick test & seems to do what you want

...provided as is/no warranties/etc :)

Comment: Cool, I'm not used to those extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to get just the last part from the current path in just batch scripting.

But, if you have [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) on your machine, it becomes relatively easy:

```
@echo off
cd /d %1
Title %~f1
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`"pwd | sed -e ""{s/.*\\//g}"""`) do dir %1 /b /l > %1\..\%%i.txt
```

---

Correction: [Alconja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712556/how-to-make-output-filename-equals-to-folder-name/712628#712628) is correct. Apparently with the extensions to batch scripting, this is possible. (I now understand the ~f as well). So, you don't need sed anymore, and this reduces to:

```
@echo off
cd /d %1
Title %~f1
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`pwd`) do dir %1 /b /l > %1\..\%%~ni.txt
```

Arguably, since you change directory, you don't need the %1 in the output path or the dir command, and you should just be able to substitute %1 for the path, so you can try (untested):

```
@echo off
cd /d %1
Title %~f1
dir /b /l > ..\%~n1.txt
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I have save it to the "SendTo" context menu.